# How to create view in RoR if skipped during controller generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

1. When I run this:

   ```
   rails generate controller hello index
   ```

   it no doubt generates hello controller, but accidentally when I run another command like this:

   ```
   rails generate controller world
   ```

   it creates the world controller successfully, but missed the `Route "world/index"` like as "hello/index". For this mistake I need to use `destroy controller` and then generate it once more, is thr some kind of mid way command that I can generate if forgotten something rather than destroying and creating every time.
2. This command

   ```
   rails generate controller contact-us index
   ```

   creates a route as `contact_us/index` or `contact_us` after changing routes.rb under config folder. How could I create a more SEO friendly URL in RoR? Like `localhost:3000/contact-us`?
3. I am working on some very basic rules to follow RoR..like 3 static pages (Home, About us, Contact Us) Just simple html content to understand more, will certainly add more features to it as well.

   ```
   localhost:3000/home
   localhost:3000/About_us
   localhost:3000/contact_us
   ```

   I created this via creating home, About_us, contact_us controller command and then changed html in views. Since I am on an initial phase, I read somewhere for static pages we can create this in our public like what we have error pages there in the folder or the approach im using is correct?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall not too many though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use rails generator it will create controller and view folder for it

```
rails generate controller test
```

will create test_controller.rb and view/test folder
    rails generate controller test index
will create test_controller.rb and view/test/index.html.erb file as well as define a route for you

However what its sounds like you are trying to do is have single controller with static pages what i would suggest you do is generate home_controller with home, aboutus, and contact actions and than map the routes to them like so

```
rails generate controller home
```

controllers/home.rb

```
HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def about_us
  end
  def contact
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/home', :to => 'home#index'
match '/About_us', :to => 'home#about_us'
match '/Contact_us' , :to=> 'home#contact_us'
```

and than define your views in

```
views/home/index.html.erb
views/home/about_us.html.erb
views/home/contact_us.html.erb
```